# New Thunderbird typeface, font and format

Tags: email, thunderbird

Somebody referred to it as GUI font rendering changed in latest update of Thunderbird, I don't know if this is correct, but for for sure it now looks different.
Enlarges the display of the message list, and the folder tree view.

Can I change it to look the way it did before this update? If not, can I use System Restore to an earlier point to get round this, and disable automatic Thunderbird updates?

Comment: Which Thunderbird version, on which OS, are you using? Can you upload a screenshot of what it looks like currently?

Comment: I am using 91.3.0 (32-bit) Thunderbird version, on Windows 7. I attach a screen shot of what it looks like. No, how do I attach a screen shot please here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally a solution that works, mine is currently set at 1.45, this works best for me.

https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/cant-change-email-font-size-thunderbird-for-macs-stuck-in-tiny-letters/

Looking around in the Web, it turned out that there are lots of complaints about the tiny fonts.

I found a solution, it is not exactly perfect but certainly gets around the tiny font size problem:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1297871

It means using “About Config” by clicking on “Config Editor”  at the very bottom of the page in: Thunderbird/Preferences/General, then accepting the “risk” (I understand there is no such risk, just a sort of in joke), then searching for “pixel” in the search field there, and clicking twice on this line: layout.css.devPixelsPerPx .

In the window that opens change the default “-1” to something bigger, but not too big, then click OK. In my case “3” works. Make sure that the “-” has been removed when changing the value from -1 to some multiple 0f 0.5, while keeping in mind that larger than 3, going by my own experience, might be too large and inconvenient, as changing from -1 on up increases all the font sizes everywhere in Thunderbird (and only in “Thunderbird”), including the “Inbox”, so everything there gets crowded and some goes out of sight if one chooses a number that is too big. The moment you click OK, you’ll see the effect of the change in the very “Config Editor” page you are in.